# Make a discord bot join a server automaticly

Tags: discord.js, puppeteer

Recently I saw another question that had a answer but it doesn't fully satisfy me. I would like to use the bot in the usage of /invite [invitelink]

Found this code that works using puppeteer but I would like it instead of setting the url by hand in code to use a var or something. I tried just changing the url to a var called url but that just gives a error

```
>(node:32664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: invite is not defined
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:62
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (E:\Folders\DiscordBot\v2\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:218:19)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (E:\Folders\DiscordBot\v2\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:107:16)
    at async invite4 (E:\Folders\DiscordBot\v2\app.js:91:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:32664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:32664) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The code I use is:

```
const invite = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://discord.com/');
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        const x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('POST', `https://discord.com/api/v6/invites/${invite}`);
        x.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);
        x.send();
    });
    //Maybe good idea to close browser after executing
};
```

Got the code from here: [How do I make a selfbot join a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57525462/how-do-i-make-a-selfbot-join-a-server)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try reading the error message? Did you understand what it said? Did you try copying and pasting any parts of it into a search engine?

Comment: I mean I tested the link and it gives the link fully working, I am not that good with puppeteer so that's why I am asking. I have been trying to fix this issue for more then a week so this is my last resort. I have absolutely no idea why this doesn't work since I saw threads that used it with a var instead of the full link so I really have no idea why this doesn't work. I would appreciate any help anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the Error is stated, that evaluation failed, because `invite` is not defined. Evaluation is the part of the code, that gets injected into the website you're trying to access.

```
>(node:32664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: invite is not defined
at __puppeteer_evaluation_script ...
```

You need to pass the `inviteCode` to the `page.evaluate()` function. In your case, you also need to pass the `token` to the function.

To pass variables inside the `page.evaluate()` function in puppeteer, I found an answer here:

[How can I pass variable into an evaluate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/how-can-i-pass-variable-into-an-evaluate-function)

So for your example, it'd look like that:

```
const invite = async (inviteCode, token) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://discord.com/');
    await page.evaluate(({inviteCode, token}) => {
        const x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        console.log(inviteCode);
        x.open('POST', `https://discord.com/api/v6/invites/${inviteCode}`);
        x.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);
        x.send();
    },{inviteCode, token});
    //Maybe good idea to close browser after executing
};
```

Like that, you can pass the arguments directly to your function like that: `invite(inviteCode, token);`