# Not able to fetch discord guild/server/channel members

Tags: python, node.js, discord, postman

Tried to get numbers of discord members using discord's API endpoint `GET/guilds/{guild.id}/members` (see [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild)).

I am using Postman to make a call to it. I set the Authorization header:

```
Authorization: "Bot ${BOT_TOKEN}"
```

The response I get is

```
{ "message": "Missing Access", "code": 50001 }
```

I also tried with `Authorization: DISCORD_CLIENT_ID`.
The response is `{ "message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0 }`.

Am I missing something? Please help me out with this.

[image]

Comment: You didn't provide proper authentication. Double-check the docs and make sure you are providing the right token.

Comment: Now, I tried login with my email and password than got token and used it with the endpoint https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/{{guild_id}}/members. Now getting the response of "Missing access" with code "50001".

So few questions arising is that.
1. Which exact token I need? Bot, App, or access token which I can get after login.
2. With working token will I be able to get any guild_id's details? (I am trying to get number of member of that guild_id)

If you can point me out with discord doc link it will be very helpful.
Thank you

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you should try out all the tokens you can access, since it already failed many times. Here's the guild docs, although I doubt it'd be much of a help because it only talks about the API and no authentication: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild

Comment: Are you sure you're interpolating the guild ID correctly? It should be `https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/YOUR_GUILD_ID/members`.

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to make sure you are using the correct `guild` id and not a `channel` id. You can enable `Developer Mode` on Discord through `User settings` -> `Advanced`, which allows you to obtain the  `guild` id by right-clicking on a `guild` (server), and then clicking on `Copy ID`.

Next, go to your application through [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), select your application and navigate to the `Bot` tab on the navigation bar to the left. From there, obtain your bot's `authentication token` that you need to pass in the headers of your request. On the same tab - since you need to get the list of `Guild Members`, and since that ["endpoint is restricted according to whether the `GUILD_MEMBERS` Privileged Intent is enabled for your application"](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-member) - scroll down to the `Privileged Gateway Intents` section and enable `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT`.

Below is a working example using the Node.js standard modules. Please note that, as described [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-member), the default `limit` of maximum number of members to return is `1`. Thus, you can adjust the `limit` in the query parameters, as below, to receive more results per request. The maximum number of results you can get per request is `1000`. Therefore, if a `guild` contains more members than that, you can keep track of the  highest user id present in each previous request, and pass it to the `after` parameter of the next request, as described in the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-member). In this way, you can obtain every member in a `guild`. Also, make sure you set the properties in `options` in the proper way, as shown below; otherwise, you might come accross `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` error, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690803/node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound).

### Update

If you haven't already, you should add your `bot` to the server you wish, by generating an invite link for your `bot` through `URL Generator` under `OAuth2` in your application settings (select `bot` from scopes). Now, you can access that URL from your browser and add the `bot` to any of your servers. If you need to, you can share the same invite link with others, so that they can add your `bot` to their servers.

**Example in Node.js**

```
const https = require('https')
const url = require('url');

GUILD_ID = "YOUR_GUILD_ID"
BOT_TOKEN = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN'
LIMIT = 10

const requestUrl = url.parse(url.format({
    protocol: 'https',
    hostname: 'discord.com',
    pathname: `/api/guilds/${GUILD_ID}/members`,
    query: {
        'limit': LIMIT
    }
}));

const options = {
    hostname: requestUrl.hostname,
    path: requestUrl.path,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bot ${BOT_TOKEN}`,
    }
}
const req = https.request(options, res => {
    res.on('data', d => {
        process.stdout.write(d)
    })
})

req.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

**Example in Python**

```
import requests
import json

GUILD_ID = "YOUR_GUILD_ID"
BOT_TOKEN = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN'
LIMIT = 10
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bot {}'.format(BOT_TOKEN)}
base_URL = 'https://discord.com/api/guilds/{}/members'.format(GUILD_ID)
params = {"limit": LIMIT}
r = requests.get(base_URL, headers=headers, params=params)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text,'\n')
#print(r.raise_for_status())
for obj in r.json():
    print(obj,'\n')
```

Comment: I followed your instructions but when I try to run I am getting this error:
{
    "message": "Missing Access",
    "code": 50001
}

Comment: This doesn't sound right. I have also added a Python version for you to test. Both the examples above should work as expected. The error you mention is thrown only if you haven't provided the correct `Guild ID`, or the bot has not been added to a server, or you haven't toggle ON `Guild_Members` (Server Members Intent) for your bot, as described above.

Comment: Oh, so do I need to add my bot in the server??? So that means I cannot fetch members of any other server other than mine? right?

Comment: You could fetch members of other servers, as long as the `bot` is added to those servers.  I have updated the answer with how you could add the `bot` to your server. The same URL could be shared with others to add the bot to their servers.

Comment: _"Bots cannot accept invites or join servers/guilds any other way than being manually invited. "_ (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55554780)). Otherwise, this would allow bots to "randomly" join servers.